How can I add a custom element inside a message using react-chat-elements?
I am currently trying to put a loading icon on messages before displaying it. I can't find anywhere on the docs if it is possible or, if so, how to do it.
This is the current JSX I have, however there is no custom attribute in the props, I could get the svg of the element and then display it as a photo message as a last resort but I would prefer to do it the easier more flexible way.
<MessageList
  dataSource={[{
    position: "left",
    type: 'text',
    title: '',
    custom: <IonSpinner name="dots"></IonSpinner>,
  }]}
/>


According to this thread, I can just use the text attribute as it can support JSX as well as a string.
<MessageList
  dataSource={[{
    position: "left",
    type: 'text',
    title: '',
    text: <IonSpinner name="dots"></IonSpinner>,
  }]}
/>

